# how to read time series data? Horizontally or vertically?

Tags: time-series

Currently I'm reading "Times series analysis and forecast by example", the data given in the appendix is just a bunch of numbers in a table, do the time series read vertically or horizontally?

Assuming $t_1$ is $17.0$, is $t_2$ $16.6$ or $17.6$?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the bottom of the table, where it explains "read down":

[image]

... so reading down the first column, we have $t_2=16.6$.

Even without the explicit instruction, I'd have guessed that you should read down because of the three missing values at the end (below 17.4) suggesting the series finished at that point. (Even without *that* secondary hint, I'd still have guessed 'read down' but I'd have been much less confident about it.)